# Is it mandatory to use Cloud9 iDE to interact with the AWS?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, cloud9-ide

I would like to know if it is mandatory to use Cloud9 IDE to interact with the amazon web services, or is it enough to have a local machine terminal ssh to AWS service?

What is the major difference of using Cloud9 IDE from the local machine ssh terminal?

I would like to accomplish building the Hyperledger fabric network, i.e., to create a Fabric network and provision a peer node in Amazon Managed Blockchain.
Here is the source where I came across Cloud9 IDE: https://github.com/aws-samples/non-profit-blockchain/blob/master/ngo-fabric/README.md, where they mentioned AWS Cloud9 IDE is one of the pre-requisites.

Comment: It's not mandatory. It might me more convenient for some tasks, especially you don't have one local workstation you work from.

Comment: There is no concept of using SSH to connect to "AWS". You could use SSH to connect to an **Amazon EC2 instance**, but that is just one of many services that AWS offers. Feel free to Edit your question to provide details of what services you intend to use and/or what you wish to accomplish on AWS, and we'll be able to provide a more-specific answer.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use Cloud9 to connect with AWS services.

AWS provides several ways of connecting with them:

- Web Management Console
- Command Line Interface (CLI)
- AWS SDKs
- CloudFormation
- REST API (which is used for example by Terraform)

To use AWS ClI on your local computer, you need to configure it with your AWS Access Key ID and Secret Access Key from IAM user which has programmatic access. https://aws.amazon.com/cli/

AWS Cloud9 comes with preinstalled AWS CLI and preconfigured IAM Role associated with it: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/using-service-linked-roles.html

From AWS perspective, the IAM Role associated with Cloud9 has less access, than IAM administration user that you would probably create for AWS CLI on your local computer.